# Previous version of app in Play Store is halted while newer version is being reviewed

Tags: android, google-play, version, release, rollout

I had the 1.2 version of the app available to all users and then uploaded the newer 1.3 version that is being reviewed. Common sense is that the 1.2 version would be available for users while the newer version is reviewed and then update to 1.3 when possible.

But the version which is available for users (as shown in the image) is the 1.0 version which was the initial application that went online to Playstore and 1.2 is halted.

[image]

This happened when I updated from 1.1 to 1.2 as well. How do I fix that for future releases?

Comment: If the previous release (1.2) was not published to 100% user-base, then it is indeed halted for new users.

Comment: So what's the way to go about it? I last updated the app 3 months ago so I don't think it would ever reach 100%.

Comment: I think DarShan means that if your *rollout* isn't set to 100% (i.e. not everyone gets the *1.2* version) then publishing *1.3* replaces *1.2* as that *preview/test* version. I don't personally know offhand if that's true, but it makes sense - the point of a partial rollout is to check a new version is ok with a limited release, before it's made available to everyone. You wouldn't want that pushed to everyone unless you explicitly allowed it, right? Especially if you're rolling out a more recent version (which implies you've made more changes that you want to test)

Comment: So if *1.2* is good to go and you're happy to make it available to everyone, try setting its rollout to *100%* before you release a newer version (it might even work right now! Worth a try I guess). Just remember that *rollout* isn't about what version users have *installed*, it's about what version is *available* to them